# SpringBoot Angular Send Image over Websocket

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm currently developing a springBoot/Angular chatApp using Websocket. I configured the websocket and it's controller, when I try to send text messages it works perfectly and the data get sent to all users subscribed to the channel, however the problem is when I try to send images over the webSocket

## here's my socket config file

```
package com.group3.camping_project.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.ByteArrayMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.BinaryMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.BinaryWebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory;
import java.util.List;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
 registry.addEndpoint("/ws-websocket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
 config.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom");
 config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setMessageSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(20000);

}

}
```

## Websocket Controller

```
@MessageMapping("/sendImageToChatroom")
// /app/chatroom
public void messaging(@Payload byte[] data) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("image uploaded succesfullyyy");
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

there other controllers work perfectly

## Angular

```
sendImageWebSocket(){
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
  const buffer = reader.result;
  const blob = new Blob([buffer!], { type: this.selectedFile.type });
  // Send the blob over the WebSocket
    const headers = {
      'content-type': this.selectedFile.type,
      'content-length': blob.size
    };
    console.log(this.selectedFile);

  this.stompClient.send(
    "/app/sendImageToChatroom",headers,blob);
});
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.selectedFile)
}
```

When I made some researches I found that I should configure the websocket to handle binary data, so I added the byteArrayMessageConverter to messageconverters.
For the first attempt I wanted to accept a multipart file and request Part which contain an entity and in the front I sent a form data but it didn't work.

So I tried to just get the image for now: the controller in the backend accepts a  binary array payload in the front i converted the file to blob and sent it to the server , without specifying the headers
`const headers =  {'content-type': this.selectedFile.type, 'content-length': blob.size};`

I got an error in the server showing the the payload value is empty , This issue was fixed by adding the headers , but for now I tried to log something in the method but doesn't show anything and I'm sure that the endpoint is correct.

here's an image showing that the websocket is working correctly and sending the data to the server .
[data sent correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVaIZ.png)

Comment: I think you can achieve this with a different approach. First upload file to server and then just pass the link of image/file